# Primefaces lazydatamodel load override not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lazydatamodel

I have a problem with overriding load of primefaces lazydatamodel. The error points at the load method. I am using primefaces 5.0. Working in Jboss Developer Studio 7.1

```
 private LazyDataModel<City> mdlCityList;
    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            try {
                this.mdlCityList = new LazyDataModel<City>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public List<City> load(int first, int pageSize,
                            String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
                            Map<String, String> filters) {
                        mdlCityList.setRowCount(cityFacade.count(filters));
                        return cityFacade.getResultList(first, pageSize, sortField,
                                sortOrder, filters);
                    }
                };
                mdlCityList.setRowCount(cityFacade
                        .count(new HashMap<String, String>()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in CityListProducer " + e);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I am implementing @Override but it still points out that:

> The method load(int, int, String, SortOrder, Map) of
>   type new LazyDataModel(){} must override or implement a
>   supertype method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overriding method now in PF 5 should look

```
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)
```

instead

```
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters)
```

`Map<String,Object>` instead `Map<String,String>` in your method

Look example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the difference between the 2 you mentioned? Are you suggesting I create a class LazyCityModel similar to the one in showcase? Isn't this possible anymore?

Comment: Difference is Map<String,Object> filters and Map<String,String> filters (Object and String type on Map like value). You should use parameters type exactly what in example (Map<String,Object> instead Map<String,String>) for overriding.

Comment: Sorry, I was so focused in comparing that ironically, I didn't see a thing. Thanks Alex! Sorry for my stupidity, been lost there for hours.

Comment: Also, remember to set lazy="true" dynamic="true" in your xhtml , if not , you wont be able to call the load() method.

Comment: easy to miss Map's second generic type